# Web App fails to return from Azure AD Authentication after deployment

Tags: azure

I have a web app that is on a IIS 10 server.  I am using Azure AD for authentication.  Everything works fine in Visual Studio 2019.  If I use the browser on the IIS server, everything works fine.  It does not work on a browser on my workstation.
When I open the web app, it redirects to login.microsoftonline.com and finds my Microsoft account.  It tries to redirect back but eventually says "Pick an account"  "We couldn't sign you in.  Please try again"
If I copy the parameter redirect_uri from the current page url, and put in a new browser, it brings me to my site authenticated.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hey @Don Boone, welcome! It would be good if you could attach some image examples.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. If neither https:// or http:// was entered in the URL, it assumed http://. Azure AD didn't like this. The solution was to add a URL rewrite in IIS to ensure https://